# Excluding cases within quotes using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a piece of code that retrieves the variable names of dictionaries from a separate file. The code:

```
import re
f = open('file.py')
f = f.readlines()
for line in f:
  line = line.replace('\n', '')
  a = re.findall(r'(\w*) *= *{', line)
  a = ''.join(a)
  if a != '':
    print(a)
```

The problem that i am having is that it returns matches that are inside a set of quotes.

For example:

```
"foo = {}" #will output 'foo', but i don't want it to be recognized.
```

It should only be picking up on dictionaries that are not in quotes. But i am unsure how to add that to the regex statement.

Current statement works for everything except for the fact that it picks up on dictionaries inside quotes:

```
(\w*) *= *{
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse Python code with regular expressions? And, if so, why?

Comment: I am trying to find all variable names of dictionaries in an external file. It is for a challenge.

Comment: I guess my point is *why are you trying to use regex*?

Comment: @Armageddon80 an ex along with expected output would be better.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using regexes to parse another python file, consider using the `ast` module, which does all the heavy lifting of actually interpreting the text for you. Once you have the syntax tree, it becomes fairly straightforward to pick out dictionary assignments.

Example:

```
#sample.py

a = {1:2, 3:4}
b = "foo = {4:8, 15:16}"
c = {1,2,3}

def f():
    d = {"Hello": "World"}
```

```
#main.py
import ast

with open("sample.py") as f:
    tree = ast.parse(f.read())

for node in ast.walk(tree):
    if isinstance(node, ast.Assign) and isinstance(node.value, ast.Dict):
        for target in node.targets:
            if isinstance(target, ast.Name):
                print target.id
```

Result:

```
a
d
```

This correctly identifies `a` and `d` as dictionaries, while avoiding the tricky cases of `c` (has a curly bracket but isn't a dict) and `foo` (has dictionary syntax, but inside a string)

Comment: This only works if the file being scanned has correct syntax, for example if they chucked in something that doesn't have valid syntax such as p={"};};};}" then the whole thing would break.

Answer (score 1):

If your dictionaries always start at the beginning of a line you could put the beginning of line delimiter (`^`) at the start of your regex and multiline enabled.

```
/^(\w+)\s*=\s*\{/gm
```

Alternatively, you could use a negative lookbehind, making sure that your dictionary name comes after a non-quote, non-word character.

```
/(?<![\w"])(\w+)\s*=\s*\{/g
```

Where `(?<![\w"])` is a negative lookbehind. It is a non-matched group that makes sure that the character before is neither a word character nor a quote.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below alternation based regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '"foo = {}" bar = {}'
>>> [i for i in re.findall(r'"[^"]*"|(\w* *= *\{)', s) if i]
['bar = {']
```